# Class Based TemplateView 404 error

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I am confused as to how to use the TemplateView in Django 1.6.

The HTML Looks like this:

```
<li><a href="/solutions">Solutions</a></li>
```

My urls.py looks like this:

```
 url(r'^/solutions$', solutions.as_view(), name='solutions'),
```

And the (entire) solutions views.py looks like this:

```
class solutions(TemplateView):

    template_name = "solutions.html"
```

Yet I still receive a 404 error  when going to www.mysite.com/solutions. I can give the entire traceback upon request. But I am sure I am doing something fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically your **url regex should not start with '/'**. 
It should be :

```
url(r'^solutions/$', solutions.as_view(), name='solutions')
```

This would work. 
You can find more about Naming URL patterns here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns

Comment: Also, you should avoid hardcoding urls in your template. Instead use the django template tag [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#url), in your example that would be: `<li><a href="{% url 'solutions' %}">Solutions</a></li>`